# Office 365 Add-in JS - AJAX PUT

Tags: ajax, office-js, office-addins

I'm having trouble with an AJAX call in an Office 365 Outlook Add-in.

I can make GET and POST calls without any issues, but when I try to use a PUT method via jQuery ajax call, it errors out on me. Just an error without any details.

Is it something on my end or are PUTs not allowed?.Any Idea?

```
 $.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "http://www.aaaaaa.com",
    dataType: 'json'
  })
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please specify the platform you're trying to make this call in the addin?
Is it Outlook Web, Mac, iOS or Win32?

Comment: I am making this call via Outlook for Mac.

Comment: Hey, are you seeing any network call happen when you make the PUT call? You can check this by using a proxy to intercept network calls. Can you write a simple code for your add-in to make a call to postman echo server and see if you get any response? (Best if you could share the proxy trace for this too):
```
var data = new Object();
data = "data"
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://postman-echo.com/put',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
      showMessage("Success:");
    },
    error: function () {
      showMessage('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Also it would be good to know if your code is working for other clients such as Outlook Web App.